# Will converting Char.GetNumericValue() to int destroy information?

Tags: c#, unicode, char, gethashcode

I am implementing `GetHashCode()`. I want to sum the values in a property called `string Id` then divide
by some constant and return the result. I am using `GetNumericValue()`:

```cs
int sum = 0;
 foreach (var ch in Id)
  sum += char.GetNumericValue(ch);
```

But it seems that `GetNumericValue` returns `double`. is it ok to convert it into an `int`?

I thought that `Unicode` characters are represented by whole number, why is `double` returned?
And is it okay to ignore it?

Comment: It seems like you don't understand what `GetNumericValue` does. Instead of trying to continue using it, you should explain what do you intend to do with `ch`, and we can suggest an appropriate method.

Comment: Why are you implementing a different hashcode for strings? Why not just `Id.GetHashCode()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is double returned?

While 0-9 are the standard digits, actually there are some **Unicode** characters that represent numbers, some of them are floating point like `⅔` or `½`. Let's get an example:

```
var ch = char.GetNumericValue('½');
Console.WriteLine(ch);// 0.5 output
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will lose data *for some values*, since this is the *numerical value* of unicode characters that *are themselves numbers* - and unicode includes characters that are non-integer numbers:

```cs
var val = char.GetNumericValue('½'); // or ¼, or ꠲, or ⳽
System.Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Comment: Wait, is GetNumericValue() for converting char to int? Isn't it for getting the Unicode character's numeric value?

Comment: @avivgood2 if you mean the code-point: nope; that would be `var codePoint = (int)c;`